# How to hide MDL tooltip with javascript

Tags: material-design-lite

When I click on my MDL save button I am disabling the button. However, the tooltip gets stuck below it when the button gets disabled.  Is there a way to hide the MDL tooltip with code?

```
<mdl.Button id="save1_Button" buttonType="mini-fab" buttonColor="primary" disabled={true}>Save</mdl.Button>
<div className="mdl-tooltip" htmlFor="save1_Button">
   Save
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a hack, but you can do it with:

```
$('.mdl-tooltip.is-active').removeClass('is-active');
```

I know, this is just a workaround, but I couldn't find a supported way of doing it.

Comment: That's the current way to go. Once the `button` is disabled, all related calculation on it stop, to clear the `tooltip` remove the `is-active` class. The source code adds `is-active` on hover anyway: https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/blob/mdl-1.x/src/tooltip/tooltip.js#L105